# Why should I use MySQL Trigger when I can validate data in application layer

Tags: php, mysql, triggers, database-performance

I don't really understand the reason of using MySQL Trigger when I can check any data in the application layer (using PHP or JavaScript, for instance) and then send it to the database. So, what are the cases when I have to use Triggers?

I Read about triggers here: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-triggers.aspx

Comment: And how you are going to know for example that this username is exists or the username && password are the same as in the database?

Comment: Using database triggers has nothing to do with validation, so the reason for your question is pretty unclear

Comment: If you google "why use database triggers" you get about 38 million results - one of those can probably answer your question...

Comment: @MarkBaker that was a mistake. I should've used the word "check". I have edited the question. Hope it makes sense now.

Comment: It still doesn't make much sense... an example of when to use a trigger might be when modifying the quantity of an item in an order_line record, use the trigger to recalculate the value of all the order_lines and store the result in the parent order record.... a big difference being that if I change that data through the database CLI rather than through the web app, it will still do the recalculation

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what performance issue you are talking about. Moreover, you got it wrong; in your application level you check for sanity of the data or check for malicious data.

Whereas, Trigger is used for to take some action based on the triggering event where the triggering event could be any DML statement (insert/update/delete). Triggers are not used for data validation or sanity checking of data.

Again, on a note something which should be taken care at DB level; should be passed to DB.

For example, in your application level you may check that the entered `Age` is not text and should be a number but in Trigger you will check that the input `Age` is in specific range (say, Age <= 100) and then do some action based on the check.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Rahul. You are saying in Trigger I will check whether the input Age is in specific range and do some action based on the check. I believe I can do that check in my php script too (eg; if age<=0 do this, if age=>80 do that). If so, then why we are using Triggers here? This is exactly where I am confused. Also, using the word "validation" was a mistake, I should've used the word "check" instead.

Comment: NO, that's just an example. What if in trigger, you want to check whether the customer already exist in DB. Can you do that check in App? Triggers are for to take some action based on certain integrity constraint check.

Comment: Actually, no! If we identify a customer by his email, then I need to access the database to check if any of the row in the table where users data is stored has that email. But again, I don't use Triggers do perform that action, so I really can't understand the use of triggers here.